# phpmyadmin error processing request 200

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I changed my Wamp's phpmyadmin config.inc.php file few days ago for auto authentication. Phpmyadmin was working fine but now whenever I click anywhere in phpmyadmin it's giving me this error in popup:

**Error in processing request**

**Error code: 200**

**Error text: OK**

This is my config.inc.php file:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false    allow editing
 *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'    disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * default display direction (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
 */
//$cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical';


/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in the documentation
 * in the doc/ folder or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 */
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Consider undoing your changes line by line on config.inc.php until it works again, and seeing which line gives you the issue.

Comment: @Pirate43 I do not remember what I changed last time

Comment: Any error message in your Apache's error log?

Comment: I don't know what was the problem, but I changed **memory_limit** to **-1** in php.ini file. And now the problem is fixed :) Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: I had this problem, but just cleared all cookies and local db storage in Chrome (right-click => Inspect => Application => expand all options under "Storage" => click each and delete). That just cured the problem on the next page reload.

Comment: if we this it is related problem with cookie then we can try to phpmyadmin link with incognito mode of google broswer. Because I have the same problem and try all below solution but no lock then I open the phpmyadmin link in the incognito broswer then working is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem, but I changed `memory_limit to -1` in php.ini file. And now the problem is fixed :)

Comment: Memory limit problem, you can just increase it to a significant amount, instead of making it unlimited. Thanks for the answer tho :)

Answer (score 3):

my problem was solved by :- **ENABLING COOKIES FOR LOCALHOST**

Comment: Please add more clarity to your answer regarding what you meant with some examples and sutff.

Comment: This one saved my day

Answer (score 2):

This is a working `phpmyadmin.conf` file. This will make phpMyAdmin throw you a login screen rather than use a hard coded userid/password

```
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

I suggest you return the `php.ini` `memory_limit` to

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

If you actually need more memory allocated to phpMyAdmin then you should change the `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file where you will find these PHP settings that will be applied to only phpMyAdmin

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking my whole config file to check for errors, I just deleted it (backed-up first, of course) and run the `/setup` script to generate a new config.inc.php file.

Problem solved. None of the above answers helped me. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the following line in phpmyadmin/config.inc.php worked for me. 
 from
`//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`
 to
  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

Now I have a language problem in phpmyadmin to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, now I just run on Incognito Mode / Private Window, and it works fine.

Comment: So, the issue you were facing was actually browser's cache [which is an important feature but can create issues sometimes](https://www.bigcommerce.com/ecommerce-answers/what-browser-cache-and-why-it-important)

Answer (score 0):

setting `$cfg['Lang'] = '';` in config.inc.php worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same. It turns out that I had blocked cookies in my browser. Enabling cookies worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used wrong url to access phpMyAdmin.
I typed wrong url but it showed phpMyAdmin page.. hm..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's a URL issue.
When you use this URL it may raise this issue `https://localhost//phpmyadmin/`

Instead try this URL to open your Mysql
`http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`